# Where to set EclipseLink properties using Glassfish if not set in persistence.xml

Tags: java, properties, eclipselink, glassfish-3, persistence.xml

Is there a way to set the EclipseLink properties (e.g. target database) in a place different from `persistence.xml`?

Rational: I have a JPA module defining the data structure and containing `persistence.xml`. The module might be used with different target databases. In a Java SE application one can set the eclipse link properties programmatically upon creation of `EntityManagerFactory`. However, when the JPA module is packaged in an EAR for the Glassfish application server the target database must be defined in `persistence.xml` ... or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RESOURCE_LOCAL persistence unit and access it the same way through EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: Are container managed transactions still supported with RESOURCE_LOCAL?